# Tinychat.com bot

Tags: java, sockets, chatbot, endpoint

Simple. Im trying to create a bot for a website called tinychat.com. However, i do understand how to make a socket connection to interact with the chat box, i have looked in the xhr section of the developer tab in chrome in order to get the socket information, but when i put that in my program, it says that the "Host cannot be resolved".
I have written bots for IRC in the past that have worked well, but i need a little assistance in connecting to the site.
Just a little nudge in the right direction would help. BTW, the program that i have written is chicken scratch, the behavior of the bot will be where most of the coding will be done, but im having issues with the connection.

```
 String tc_string = "wss0703.tinychat.com:25976";
        int PORT = 21037;
        SocketAddress addy = new InetSocketAddress(tc_string, PORT); //no need for the 'new' keyword since it is a static method
        Socket S1 = new Socket();
        S1.connect(addy);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the `InetSocketAddress` constructor is a hostname. It cannot contain a port number, like `:25976`.